# How to check my private IP address? CG-NAT or Double-NAT configuration

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat

To my knowledge, there are three type of IP addresses:

1. A local IP which is 192.168.x.x
2. A WAN IP which is the one you can get from websites like [iplocation.net](https://iplocation.net)
3. A private IP address which some routers report on the status page which looks like 100.x.x.x, you can only have this IP if your ISP is using a CG-NAT or someother type of Double-NAT.

My question is, how do I check my private IP address without accessing my router's configuration address (192.168.1.1)?

For example how do I check the private IP address with CMD?

1. The local IP address can easily be found with `ipconfig` command.
2. The WAN IP address can be found with this command:

   `nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com`
3. What is the command to get the private IP address?

Side question: The private IP address when entered in a browser, opens the router's configuration if you're behind a CG-NAT, but on another ISP, when I enter my WAN's IP address in the browser, it also opens the router's configuration, what type of NAT is this?

A little backgorund:

In the past I had an ADSL ISP which was using CG-NAT and I could see my private IP address in my router's config, and due to CG-NAT, I was not able to forward my ports. But now I'm using another ISP which is VDSL and I bought a new modem router for it, and this ISP also does not enable me to do port forwarding, but when I go to router's settings I can not check my private IP, I need to know why port forwarding is not working for me. If I confirm that there is a private IP address in the works, I will know that I'm behind some typed of Double-NAT so I will give up on port forwarding. And to check the private IP address, I thought the problem was with the modem router that it's not showing me it, so I'm searching for a way to check the private IP without the router's config.

Answer (score 2):

Private IP addresses by definition is just a an IP address within a private network range.

`10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16`

I believe you're confusing private addresses with what's referred to as "shared address space" ([RFC 6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598)) this is the `100.64.0.0/10` network used by carrier grade NATing.

Comment: I did confuse them, yes. I updated my question. +1

Comment: Ah, thank you I see the reason for your question now. Port Forwarding will not work if your behind a CG-NAT, you'd have to use some sort of reverse tunneling service to accomplish that. However you should be able to tell if you're behind a CG-NAT by looking at the WAN IP on your router/modem, if it's a 100.64.0.0/10 IP than that will explain why your port forwarding isn't working. If it's a Public IP than depending on the port in question your ISP might be blocking it or your config might not be correct.

Comment: You may also be double NATing yourself with multiple "routers", try a trace route to an outside IP and see if you jump through several private IP's before you get to a public one.